# Cherrypy cannot find wsgiserver module when packed with cxfreeze

Tags: python, cherrypy, cx-freeze

I am deploying a cherrypy app by packing into a set of executable files with cx_freeze.

I am using python 3 (via scl in CentOS). In order to compile the binaries I run:

```
scl enable python33 -- cxfreeze server.py
```

where server.py is the entry script.

When I execute the resulting file, the server starts and immediately stops with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 205, in publish
    output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 167, in start
    self.httpserver, self.bind_addr = self.httpserver_from_self()
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 157, in httpserver_from_self
    from cherrypy import _cpwsgi_server
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1616, in _handle_fromlist
    _call_with_frames_removed(import_, from_name)
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    loader.load_module(name)
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpwsgi_server.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cherrypy import wsgiserver
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1616, in _handle_fromlist
    _call_with_frames_removed(import_, from_name)
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    loader.load_module(name)
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cherrypy/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    exec('from .wsgiserver3 import *')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1531, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    raise exc
ImportError: No module named 'cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver3'
```

The cxfreeze script output contains, among the rest, this line:

```
Missing modules:
[...]
? wsgiserver2 imported from cherrypy.wsgiserver
[...]
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.
```

In /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/cherrypy/wsgiserver/__init__.py I can see:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    from wsgiserver2 import *
else:
    # Le sigh. Boo for backward-incompatible syntax.
    exec('from .wsgiserver3 import *')
```

I wonder why wsgiserver is not imported correctly.

I also tried to include the `wsgiserver3` module explicitly in setup.py:

```
buildOptions = {
    'packages' : ['cherrypy'],
    'includes' : ['cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver3'],
    'excludes' : [],
    'path' : sys.path,
}

import sys
base = 'Win32Service' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('server.py', base=base, targetName = 'myapp')
]

setup(name='Myapp',
      version = '1.0beta1',
      description = 'My App',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

Any hints?

Thanks,

gm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question included the answer. *cxfreeze* must be doing some sort of dependency analysis. I don't know exactly what the method is, it can be an AST traversal for instance, but what it is doing is looking for `import`s. When a library does a dynamic import like `exec('from .wsgiserver3 import *')` *cxfreeze* won't recognize it. Thus you need to list such modules explicitly in *cxfreeze* configuration. I see configuration option call [`--include-modules`](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/script.html#cmdoption--include-modules).

Btw, for the same reason of dynamic import CherryPy 3.5 (as far as I can remember) wheel distribution lacked the same `wsgiserver3` module.

## Update

Here's a quote from documentation section [`distutils commands`](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils-commands):

> To specify options in the script, use underscores in the name. For example:
>
> ```
> setup(options = {'build_exe': {'init_script':'Console'}} )
> ```
>
> To specify the same options on the command line, use dashes, like this:
>
> ```
> python setup.py build_exe --init-script Console
> ```

## Update 2

Okay, I pip-installed cx_freeze (not that fast, only with help of [this comment](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/32/cant-compile-cx_freeze-in-ubuntu-1304#comment-13195058)) and did the test myself.

*app.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import cherrypy


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return 'Hello world!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/')
```

*setup.py*

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


options = {
  'build_exe' : {
    'includes' : 'cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver3'
  }
}
executables = [Executable('app.py')]

setup(
  name        = 'CherryPyApp',
  version     = '0.1',
  description = 'Testing CherryPy wsgiserver3 dynamic import',
  options     = options,
  executables = executables
)
```

It does work with `{'includes': 'cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver3'}`, it doesn't without it, `ImportError("No module named 'cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver3'",)`.

Comment: Thanks. It works if I add the `--include-modules=cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver3` command line option, but not if I add the module to the `includes` list in setup.py (see config file I just add to my post). How do I add this option to my config file?

Comment: @gattumarrudu Take a look.

Comment: I tried exactly the same thing to no avail. I was surprised that this is not documented and so I guessed that `includes`, which is documented and described very similarly as the `include-modules` command line option, would have the same effect.